ASUS USB-AX55 Nano isn't getting recognized on my Ubuntu
I recently installed the latest version of Ubuntu on my desktop PC.
This PC doesn't have an internal on motherboard WiFi adapter, so I had to buy an external USB WiFi adapter.
I purchased the ASUS USB-AX55 Nano WiFi adapter and connected it to one of the USB slots on my machine and the system did recognize it when I typed the the lsusb command but for some reasons WiFi isn't turning on and I can't connect to the internet.
Need your help on how to install ASUS USB-AX55 Nano external USB WiFi adapter and make it work.
Thanks.

No such thing as latest version of Ubuntu. Please edit the question and add the real actual version info.

Please edit the question to include results from terminal for uname -r; lsusb

I have the same device (Asus AX-55) and under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and 24.04 LTS, I have installed the driver (which is not included with Ubuntu) from the following link. There you will find complete instructions how to install the required driver for the Realtek rtl8852bu chipset used in this device. The install script adds the module to dkms and therefore the driver will automatically be updated alongside any kernel upgrades. Do fully read the information in the link, it will answer all related questions.
